# Is current request being made over SSL with Azure deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, ssl, https

```
context.Request.IsSecureConnection
```

Always returns false in an Azure deployment **even when the connection is being served over HTTPS**.  After looking through the headers sent for an Azure deployed site I've found:

```
X-Forwarded-Proto=https
```

Does this header guarantee that the client connection to the website is under HTTPS in the same way that `context.Request.IsSecureConnection` does?

Comment: in the case of azure app service websites both http and https endpoints are exposed. In case of asp.net you can make revent users from accessing your website using anything other than HTTPS by adding redirection to https in the web.config

Comment: @Aravind, that's not what I'm asking I'm afraid.  The site is running in HTTPS, and visitors are forced onto it.  However in an Azure deployment, the site is behind a load balancer which means `Request.IsSecureConnection` always returns false.

Comment: Ok. You feel that someone would be able to access that site via that insecure channel ? I feel that this property does not get set properly or something. I am not too sure though. but i don't think there would be an insecure channel left open.

Comment: The more interesting question would be "If I craft that header and still send it over plain http, does it get overwritten by the Azure ARR front end layer?" Actually no, "how can you tell who added the header in?" - that's the question.

Comment: The SSL connection is only between the client and the load balancer, which terminates it. Behind the LB, everything is plain HTTP.
If you redirect HTTP to HTTPS in the web.config file, you are assured that you are using HTTPS between the client and Azure, which is probably what you need.

Comment: And if you're like "I have my doubts with the redirect thing" you can always deploy an App Service Environment, cut off 80/TCP entierly in the Network Security Group attached to the ASE Subnet, then host your Web App on the ASE.

Comment: @cdelmas yes that's what I need to know, is the client - azure connection over SSL.  Does inclusion of `X-Forwarded-Proto=https` guarantee this?  I can re-write all URL's to SSL no problem, but some pages (such as payment pages) I want to ensure they are served over SSL on load, not just assume they are through re-write rules.

Comment: Do you have the [RequireHttps] attribute in the controller, (warning it's not the safest way to ask for https) more infos: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/02/implemnting-https-everywhere-in-asp-net-mvc-application/

Comment: @GaelSa, that's not answering my question sorry.  I can force the client onto HTTPS, but as an extra check in my site I want to be able to check 100% definitely the page is being served over HTTPS.  This is important if for any reason the implementation of HTTPS fails I want to stop some functionality on the website (for example on the payment pages).

Comment: @TomGullen : Try verifying the signature of SSL certificate. Based on that you can stop the functionality.

Comment: @TomGullen: In case if you are using Azure, please use Public-Key-Pins to have the SSL signature mapped over there.

Comment: @Thennarasan, and that will make `context.Request.IsSecureConnection` return true?

Comment: @TomGullen: Yes I am, since in your last comment you told that " I can force the client onto HTTPS, but as an extra check in my site I want to be able to check 100% definitely the page is being served over HTTPS." in case if you don't want implement verification signature or PKP, You can do below, `If HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(False) Then    Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl) End If`

Comment: @Thennarasan You misunderstand the question.  In Azure, `Request.IsSecureConnection` **is always false even when it is being served over SSL**.  Your code would create an endless redirect loop.

Comment: also, if you are using Azure, there is a free module when you go to dev mode always load the app from http to https. So it will load 100% https.

Comment: Right, I've rephrased the original question as I'm guessing it's not entirely clear and is causing confusion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### IMPORTANT NOTE:

The custom check referred to in my answer is no longer required for ASP.NET on .NET Framework 4.7 and ASP.NET Core 2.0.

Both `HttpContext.Request.IsHttps` (Core) and `HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection` will return `True` if the request originated over HTTPS in Azure App Service.

That's what i tested with, it may have happened sooner in the life of those stacks (e.g. .NET Framework 4.6.x). You should be fine in any case since App Service now runs your application on top of .NET Framework 4.7.

You most probably have to make the check for any other programming stack.

---

> I'm not asking how to force HTTPS, I'm asking why in Azure deployment is `context.Request.IsSecureConnection` returning `false` even when the request is over HTTPS.

Here's why:

[image: Azure App Service Application Request Routing]

The Azure App Service frontend layer **TERMINATES** the TLS channel (aka TLS offloading) and opens a new **plain HTTP** connection to your Web Worker, where your code lives. Routing is performed by [ARR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Request_Routing) (Application Request Routing).

Source:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/AZR305
(View slides, Slide 12)

Therefore, from the point of view of your code every single request is "insecure".

`X-Forwarded-Proto=https` hints about the original request (that hit the frontends).

If checks have to be made, make them against `X-ARR-SSL` instead.

ARR is attaching a special request header to every request that arrives over HTTPS. The value contained in `X-ARR-SSL` provides information about the TLS server certificate that was used to secure the TCP connection between the client (i.e. browser) and the ARR frontend.

e.g.:

```
X-ARR-SSL: 2048|256|C=US, S=Washington, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation,
           OU=Microsoft IT, CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA2|CN=*.azurewebsites.net
```

A whole more info around that here:
https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/12/secure-by-default-with-ssl-in-windows.html

Tomasz is the author of the [**iisnode**](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) project, which is the mechanism for running Node applications on IIS in Azure App Service.

### EXECUTIVE SUMMARY

App Service uses Application Request Routing, which is also the point where TLS is terminated. Since the traffic that hits your web worker will then be plain HTTP, you need to check this header to tell if the request originated over TLS:

```
if (request.headers['x-arr-ssl'])
{
    // We're good
}
else
{
    // Request made over plain HTTP
}
```

If you're running on .NET Framework 4.7 or .NET Core 2.0, you do not need to make this check, there's baked in logic to return the correct value for `HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection` and `HttpContext.Request.IsHttps` (.NET Core).

Comment: And there's no way to disable the TLS/SSL Termination behavior and have the request appear as a secure https to your application code?  Or is this behavior necessary because Azure doesn't actually install certs on every application, but only at the termination point?

Comment: TLS handshake happens in the frontend layer, way before your web app is touched by the (now proxied) request. No way to change that, this is a multi-tenant PaaS service. If you really want to control TLS yourself and still call it PaaS, look at Service Fabric or Kubernetes.

Comment: ARR is being replaced by YARP, so the header check might be revisited. Hopefully Microsoft configures YARP to return the same header.

Comment: I was surprised why AppServiceHTTPLogs table' SPort column value is always 80. Now i can understand this is due to ssl offloading by "Frontend Tier" of app service architecture. 
more details i have found in 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/february/azure-inside-the-azure-app-service-architecture

Answer (score -1):

Not sure whether this will be helpful for you.

2 option.

First option:
ASP.NET MVC RequireHttps Attribute that can be used to decorate a controller or a specific action. this is by far the simplest way to force an HTTPS redirect.

```
[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult Secure()
{
    return View();
}
```

Second Option
URL Rewrite

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<configuration> 
<system.webServer> 
<rewrite> 
  <rules> 
    <rule name="Enforce SSL" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="/?(secure.*)" ignoreCase="true" /> 
      <conditions> 
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" /> 
      </conditions> 
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" /> 
    </rule> 
  </rules> 
</rewrite> 
</system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Above are the options for you 100% confirmation to ensure the request is HTTPS

Comment: Not relevant to question sorry.  I'm not asking how to force HTTPS, I'm asking why in Azure deployment is `context.Request.IsSecureConnection` returning false **even when the request is over HTTPS**

Comment: @TomGullen: Have you tried adding [RequireHttps] and after that also did you get false?

Comment: Is this for webform or webapi?