# How to fetch SSL Certificate for django project in Azure?

Tags: django, azure, ssl, https

I have my django project in Azure named

```
> djangoproj.azurewebsites.net
```

I would like to provide SSL layer for this application and when I try to use openssl in Azure console, I get the following error

```
> openssl req -sha256 -new -nodes -keyout djangoproj.key -out proj.csr -newkey rsa:2048
D:\home\site\wwwroot
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
..................+++
.......................................+++
unable to write 'random state'
writing new private key to 'djangoproj.key'
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:problems making Certificate Request
```

Problems making Certificate Request.

May I know how to get a proper SSL certificate for my app in azure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how TLS works in Azure App Service. TLS is terminated at the Frontend layer. Your application only has to deal with plain HTTP.

[image: TLS-and-ARR]

#### If you need to check if the request was made over HTTPS:

Application Request Routing (ARR) is attaching a special request header to every request that arrives over HTTPS. The value contained in `X-ARR-SSL` provides information about the TLS server certificate that was used to secure the TCP connection between the client and the ARR.

e.g.:

```
X-ARR-SSL: 2048|256|C=US, S=Washington, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation,
           OU=Microsoft IT, CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA2|CN=*.azurewebsites.net
```

My other answer here has more on that topic:
[Is current request being made over SSL with Azure deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501618/is-current-request-being-made-over-ssl-with-azure-deployment/38726543#38726543)

> May I know how to get a proper SSL certificate for my app in azure ?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site/

You get free TLS on ***https**://{site}.azurewebsites.net*, that is if you don't really need a custom domain or just looking to build a quick proof of concept.