# Why use a Reverse Proxy to front an Azure Website?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, arr

What are some legitimate use-cases for fronting an Azure "Web App" service with a reverse proxy (i.e. ARR)?

I'm specifically interested in security considerations.  For the purposes of this question, let's assume load balancing is handled by the Azure load balancer and the proxy would not perform any additional features such as caching or compression.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Load Balancer is a Layer-4 component. **ARR is a Layer-7 router**, therefore it can do *sticky sessions* (instance affinity) and health checking.

In App Service it also does TLS offloading, which is pretty nice since your application code only has to deal with plain HTTP. More on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38726543/4148708

If you don't need/want any of that, then by all means, go to Cloud Services, VM Scale Sets or vanilla VMs.