# Securing .NET Core API on Azure - still accepting HTTP with RequireHttpsAttribute set

Tags: .net, api, azure, asp.net-core

I use POSTMAN (https://www.getpostman.com/) to test my API deployed to Azure (using the *.azurewebsites.net SSL cert). The API is a standard MVC .NET Core API.

Based on the Pluralsight Tutorial (https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnetcore-implementing-securing-api) I added the RequireHttpsAttribute option in startup.cs as described.

`services.AddMvc( opt => opt.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()) )`

Yet I still get response data back when using HTTP (not HTTPS) from POSTMAN.

Any thoughts what I might be doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: RequiredHttps doesn't prevent you to connect to port 80 (http), it will only force a redirect to port 443 (https)

Comment: @Tseng thanks -  so it is redirecting to 443 and using SSL to deliver the response? Just that I don't see that in postman?

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosted in App Service? If so, there is no HTTPS beyond the frontends.

Check for the presence of `X-ARR-SSL` header instead.
See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38726543/4148708

Comment: Yes I am. That could well be the reason then. I will try this and report back (tomorrow now) :-)