# HTTPS in Spring Boot web app deployed in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, tomcat, ssl, spring-boot, https

How do I enable HTTPS for a `Spring Boot` web application deployed on an Azure App Service (Tomcat 8.5, Java 8)? I have the custom domain and an SSL certificate from Verisign already. Most blogs cover the embedded Tomcat server scenario and using self signed certificates, which did not help me, since I am deploying the Spring Boot web application as a WAR in the Azure Tomcat-based app service. I added the following line:

```
server.port=443
```

and deployed the web app from STS to Azure. But I don't get back any response if I access https://custom.domain.name and if I try to acccess http://custom.domain.name, I get a 404 with the following message

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target
>   resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

The way I need this to work is to process HTTPS requests only and if request is made over HTTP, then force it to HTTPS.

Comment: Did you update your web.xml to enforce SSL communications as well? http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/ForcingSSLForSectionsOfYourWebsite

Comment: I added two properties in `application.properties` - `security.require-ssl=true` and `server.port=443` with fully Java based configuration. Since this is a Spring Boot app, I was not sure if I can/should add a web.xml.

Comment: so you use embedded spring boot, right?

Comment: @chenrui if you are referring to embedded Tomcat servlet container, no I am using an Azure App Service based Tomcat which is PaaS (similar to AWS Beanstalk, etc.). This is equivalent to deploying the Spring Boot web application as a WAR to an external Tomcat server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen to **80/TCP** instead, because there's already TLS offloading applied to traffic before it hits your application code.

Both `https://your.domain` and `http://your.domain` will end up on **80/TCP** in your app, without you handling any of the TLS.

Check out this answer for a more comprehensive explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38726543/4148708

Comment: I was not cognizant of an implicit front end layer. So I removed  the property from `application.properties` and I re-deployed to Azure. I can now hit http://custom.domain.name just fine, but https://custom.domain.name yielded `could not get a response` when I test in Postman. Turns out it was a Postman setting, so it works just like you described. How do I force HTTPS only, if I want to refuse requests over HTTP?

Comment: In case my earlier comment was ambiguous, I want to clarify that your suggestion worked. I did not have to do anything else in the application. Turning off SSL certificate verification in Postman's settings got both HTTP and HTTPS requests working. There is an Azure extension I enabled to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS, so things appear to be working as intended. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you add a rewrite rule in web.config to force HTTPS. Check the presence of `X-ARR-SSL` header in requests if your app's "life" depends on it (or you're under regulation mandating you to provide proof of encryption), otherwise the rewrite rule is enough.