# Azure App Service terminating https before application?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, httpcontext

I'm building an asp.net core web application on framework 2.2 and hosting on an azure app service on a linux app service plan.

Inside my application I inspect [HttpRequest.Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.scheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2).  Running locally this returns `https` if I make a request using https.  Running on azure it returns `http`.

It appears Azure App Services is terminating the SSL connection and proxying to my app.  **Is there a way to configure Azure App Services so the https request makes it to my application unmodified?  Or at least [HttpRequest.Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.scheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2) matches the original request?**

---

I've built a sample diagnostic page to show this behavior:

```cs
var healthStatus = new
{
    Port = context.Request.Host.Port?.ToString() ?? "unknown",
    context.Request.Scheme,
    context.Request.IsHttps,
    Headers = context.Request.Headers.Select(x => $"{x.Key}:{x.Value}").ToArray()
 };

context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(healthStatus));
```

Debugging in VS Locally: `https://localhost:1234/ping`:

```
{
   "Port":1234,
   "Scheme": "https",
   "IsHttps": true,
   "Headers": <standard headers - nothing interesting>
}
```

Deploying to Azure App Services: `https://appServiceExample.myDomain.com/ping`:

```
{
   "Port":"unknown",
   "Scheme": "http",
   "IsHttps": false,
   Headers: [ 
     // there are several more headers, but only these looked interesting:
     "X-Forwarded-For:195.206.xxx.xxx:6922",
     "X-Forwarded-Proto:https",
     "X-AppService-Proto:https"
    ]
}
```

**As a workaround:** Could I solve this problem my relying on the `X-AppService-Proto` or `X-Forwarded-Proto` header?  But this seems a bit of a hack, as I'd rather inspect the original incoming request - and I'm unsure how reliable these headers are.

Comment: Only a guess here, but does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-ssl-cert-load#make-the-certificate-accessible if there is a setting required to enable the asp.net stack to see SSL certificates, I'd expect it to have to be enabled for any SSL-handling code to work.

Comment: @tomw unfortunately it doesn't.  I do have SSL configured in the App Service, my cert is uploaded and everything looks fine from the browser side.  It's only server side that the SSL seems to terminate before my application code is invoked.

Comment: @Philip, see my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501618/is-current-request-being-made-over-ssl-with-azure-deployment/38726543#38726543

Comment: @evilSnobu - thanks, figured this had to be a duplicate - but my google skills were failing me.

Comment: This is a duplicate, it should be closed as a duplicate.  I voted to close it.  But I think it needs a few move close votes.

Answer (score 3):

Just summarize your comment.

The Azure App Service frontend layer **TERMINATES** the TLS channel (aka TLS offloading) and opens a new **plain HTTP** connection to your Web Worker, where your code lives. Routing is performed by ARR (Application Request Routing).

Therefore, from the point of view of your code every single request is "**insecure**".

`X-Forwarded-Proto=https` hints about the original request (that hit the frontends).

If checks have to be made, make them against `X-ARR-SSL` instead.

For more details, you could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501618/is-current-request-being-made-over-ssl-with-azure-deployment).