# How to use an Azure App Service Certificate with Java Spring to enable SSL

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, ssl, jhipster

I want to deploy a Spring Boot Application, generated with JHipster, to Azure App Service and enable HTTPS/SSL. I bought an App Service Certificate and bound it to a custom domain of my app service. How can I use that certificate in a config file of my Spring Application?

I also set the `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` variable to my ceritificate's thumbprint.

```
server:
    port: 443
    ssl:
        key-store: keystore.p12
        key-store-password: <your-password>
        keyStoreType: PKCS12
        keyAlias: <your-application>
```

I don't know how to access the certificate from here. What is the path to the keystore, and how do I obtain the password and key alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to configure the SSL certificate to your web app on Azure portal.

Because there is a front tier before your spring boot application. The front tier will handle the security connections (HTTPS) with clients, but communicate with your web app with HTTP.

For more detailed explanation, you may refer to this post: [Is current request being made over SSL with Azure deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501618/is-current-request-being-made-over-ssl-with-azure-deployment/38726543#38726543)