# How reverse proxy with SSL/TSL and plain traffic works?

Tags: azure, docker, ssl, reverse-proxy, azure-web-app-service

I have a containerized Docker ASP.NET Core application created with

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1.3-alpine
```

When launched the only reference to the port is this ENV variable from the base image

```
ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:80
```

I deployed the app to Azure, setuped the registry and created a new Web Application.
I setup the TLS/SSL settings for working with https only.

Everythings works.

Question:

I want to know how this is possible since I don't config the certificate on my container, I suppose the Kudu service (the reverse proxy) rebind the 443 port to the 80 of the container. Is this true ? The plain http traffic between Kudu and the container on port 80 can cause a possible security hole ?

If I deploy a container with NGINX as a reverse-proxy for ASP.NET Core I must configure the TSL/SSL into NGINX ? On ASP.NET Core ? None at all ?

I want to understand how Kudu, NGINX, and the reverse proxy in general works with and without SSL/TSL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a [Reverse Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) the client never connects to the HTTP server in your application, in your case [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1).  The connections you get are requests coming from the Reverse Proxy, and you send your responses back to the Reverse Proxy.  Most HTTP stuff is copied from the incoming client request and passed along to your application, but the Reverse Proxy can terminate the SSL tunnel, offload the Authentation, and perform other request transformations.

Comment: Basically the client connect via **http(s)** to Azure, next the Kudu proxy forward the request to kestrel via **http**. And the plain http is not a concern because is made on internal azure network. With the same logic I can install nginx in front on kestrel. Is this correct ?

Comment: It's the App Service Front-Ends, not Kudu, but yes.  The architecture is more explicitly documented for App Service Environments, but it's the same for the shared hosting plans.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/using-an-ase

Comment: David, thanks for your patience. Your answer raise another question: _It's the App Service Front-Ends, not Kudu, but yes_ What's the role of Kudu ? Many thanks.

Comment: "Kudu is the engine behind git deployments in Azure App Service. It can also run outside of Azure. " https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu

Comment: Check out the diagram at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38726543/4148708